# Problems with vertical y-axis alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to get the vertical axes aligned in the following figure but having trouble.  In particular, the y-axis of the first and last figure in the 3rd row have to be aligned with those of the previous rows. Other issues are:

1. asterisk and the equal to signs are not at the center,
2. the figures in the last column are not to scale, and
3. the font is too big.

Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pgfpages,mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Examples}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \matrix{
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (conv1) {$\ast$};

   \&\begin{axis}[%
     axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (equal1) {$=$};

   \&\begin{axis}[%
     axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4,8},
     xticklabels={0,$T$,$2T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (4,1) (8,0)};
   \end{axis}\\

   \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,8},
     xticklabels={0,$2T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (8,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (conv2) {$\ast$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (equal2) {$=$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4,8,12},
     xticklabels={0,$T$,$2T$,$3T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=13,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (4,1) (8,1) (12,0)};
   \end{axis}\\

   \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-4,0},
     xticklabels={$-T$,0},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=-5,xmax=5,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     height=3cm,
     y tick label style={anchor=west},
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(-4,0) (-4,1) (0,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (conv3) {$\ast$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (equal3) {$=$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-4,0,4},
     xticklabels={$-T$,$0$,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=-5,xmax=5,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$},
     height=3cm,
     xlabel={\empty}, x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(-4,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not setting `xmin` and `xmax` to the same values for each graph? The font size can be reduced using `\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}}`

Comment: Making xmin and xmax resulted in the axes being aligned.  Thanks.  Is there a way for aligning them without making xmin and xmax the same?  Just curious.  The fonts are also now better, following your suggestion.  The only issue remaining is moving the "*" and "=" signs to the center.  Has this to be done manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add

```
every axis/.append style={
footnotesize,
height=3cm,
unit vector ratio=1 4 1,
execute at end axis={
   \coordinate (O) at (current axis.east -| current axis.origin);
   },
anchor=O,
```

to the `tikzpicture` options, you get

[image]

Does that look better? (The common settings added in the `every axis` style is removed from the individual axes.)

Note also that `xlabel=\empty` is kind of strange. The `\empty` macro is intended for ticks (`xtick`/`ytick`/`ztick`), for the case where you don't want any ticks at all. If you don't need an `xlabel`, just remove `xlabel=..` altogether. (And then you can also remove the `x label style` of course.)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pgfpages,mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Examples}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
   ampersand replacement=\&,
   baseline=(current bounding box.center),
   every axis/.append style={
    footnotesize,
    height=3cm,
    unit vector ratio=1 4 1,
    execute at end axis={
       \coordinate (O) at (current axis.east -| current axis.origin);
       },
    anchor=O
    }
   ]
  \matrix{
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (conv1) {$\ast$};

   \&\begin{axis}[%
     axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (equal1) {$=$};

   \&\begin{axis}[%
     axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4,8},
     xticklabels={0,$T$,$2T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (4,1) (8,0)};
   \end{axis}\\

   \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,8},
     xticklabels={0,$2T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (8,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (conv2) {$\ast$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (equal2) {$=$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4,8,12},
     xticklabels={0,$T$,$2T$,$3T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=13,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (4,1) (8,1) (12,0)};
   \end{axis}\\

   \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-4,0},
     xticklabels={$-T$,0},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=-5,xmax=5,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     y tick label style={anchor=west},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(-4,0) (-4,1) (0,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (conv3) {$\ast$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& \node (equal3) {$=$};

   \&\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xtick={-4,0,4},
     xticklabels={$-T$,$0$,$T$},ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
     xmin=-5,xmax=5,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$},
     ]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(-4,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone.  The above is indeed what I want.  I had not stated clearly in my original post that I wanted "*" and "=" to be in the center vertically,  as given in the above solution.  Thanks to the other solutions as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here a solution to center `\ast` and `=` symbols between plots

- First you need to name plots with `name=` A,B,...,I.
- Then you can place nodes containing `\ast` and `=` symbols like this

---

```
 \foreach \i/\j in {A/B,D/E,G/H}
{\path (\i.south east)--node{$\ast$}(\j.south west);}
\foreach \i/\j in {B/C,E/F,H/I}
{\path (\i.south east)--node{$=$}(\j.south west);}
```

**Complete Code**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pgfpages,mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Examples}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&,baseline=(current bounding box.center),
  every axis/.append style={ymin=0, ymax=1.2,height=3cm,
     font=\scriptsize,xlabel={\empty}, 
     x label style={anchor=north},
     ylabel={\empty}, y label style={anchor=west},
     axis lines=middle,,xmin=0,xmax=10}]

  \matrix[column sep=3mm]{
    \begin{axis}[name=A,axis lines=middle, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},yticklabels={$1$},ytick={1}]
          \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& 

   \&\begin{axis}[%
     name=B, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& 

   \&\begin{axis}[%
     name=C, xtick={0,4,8},
     xticklabels={0,$T$,$2T$},ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (4,1) (8,0)};
   \end{axis}\\

   \begin{axis}[name=D, xtick={0,8},
     xticklabels={0,$2T$},ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (8,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& 

   \&\begin{axis}[name=E, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},
     ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& 

   \&\begin{axis}[name=F, xtick={0,4,8,12},
     xticklabels={0,$T$,$2T$,$3T$},
     xmax=13,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (4,1) (8,1) (12,0)};
   \end{axis}\\

   \begin{axis}[name=G, xtick={-4,0},
     xticklabels={$-T$,0},
     xmin=-5,xmax=5,ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(-4,0) (-4,1) (0,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& 

   \&\begin{axis}[name=H, xtick={0,4},
     xticklabels={0,$T$},ytick={1},yticklabels={$1$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none,const plot]
     coordinates
     {(0,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}

   \& 

   \&\begin{axis}[name=I, xtick={-4,0,4},
     xticklabels={$-T$,$0$,$T$},
     xmin=-5,xmax=5,ytick={1},yticklabels={$T$}]
     \addplot+[very thick,mark=none]
     coordinates
     {(-4,0) (0,1) (4,0)};
   \end{axis}\\
 };

 \foreach \i/\j in {A/B,D/E,G/H}
{\path (\i.south east)--node{$\ast$}(\j.south west);}
\foreach \i/\j in {B/C,E/F,H/I}
{\path (\i.south east)--node{$=$}(\j.south west);} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}
```

\end{document}
[image]

Comment: Ehm, the y-axes are not aligned, and the `\ast` and `=` is not centered vertically on the axes, as requested.

Comment: I think OP want `\ast` and `=`  to be centered only horizontally.

Comment: Hm, perhaps you're right, it's not really clear. We'll see what (s)he says. (Of course, moving them up in your case is just a matter of removing `south` in the loops.)